Error in CategoriesProductCollectionsAdmin Settings
I added a plugin SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.SmartProductCollections version 4.4. While added product in category I'm getting error which state that  Admin/CategoriesProductCollectionsAdmin/GetProductsGroupTabs not found. I tried alot to resolve this error but cloud not successes.

It's a paid plugin, and others cannot install to check the issue. Ask in their support forum.

Are you sure the plugin of SevenSpikes.Core already has been installed on your website? Because some prerequisites of Seven Spike plugins have been supplied by that!
